# Nuget Package availability to public after publishing

Tags: package, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-server

How long will it take for the package to be available in search result on [Nuget](http://www.Nuget.org). Once we publish the package to the Nuget server?

if some have some experience about that please share it with me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My last package upload was instantly available.
I uploaded it via the web interface, not with `nuget.exe`.